# Unable to load localhost URL in Cypress.io

Tags: javascript, automation, automated-tests, localhost, cypress

I am facing an issue in Cypress.io, when I load local URL it gives an error every time. I have even added the { "baseUrl": "http://localhost:4200" } in cypress.json file as mentioned in the official documentation.

Following are my couple of test scripts:

```
it('successfully loads', () => {
  cy.visit('http://localhost:4200/') // change URL to match your dev URL
})
it('successfully load', () => {
    cy.visit('/') // change URL to match your dev URL
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why the error occurs in this case, but if you just need to turn it off - you can add this line under your cy.visit call. The error should not occur again.

```
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => { return false; })
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working fine now :)

Answer (score 14):

I had this same problem and troubleshooted it for hours. I fixed this by modifying `npm run dev` script in `package.json` to `"dev": "vite --host"`. This opens the hosting to your network so Cypress can access it reliably.

Comment: I don't need this on my Linux machine but encountered the same issue with Windows and you are right. Adding --host it works now.

Comment: omgeeeee thank you. Friggin vite

Answer (score 1):

In my case running Angular like this solved the problem:

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Thanks, worked instantly when I tried this!